# Grouping elements of a list into sublists (maybe by using guava)

Tags: java, list, function, grouping, guava

I want to group elements of a list. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
public static <E> List<List<E>> group(final List<E> list, final GroupFunction<E> groupFunction) {

    List<List<E>> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (final E element : list) {

        boolean groupFound = false;
        for (final List<E> group : result) {
            if (groupFunction.sameGroup(element, group.get(0))) {
                group.add(element);
                groupFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! groupFound) {

            List<E> newGroup = Lists.newArrayList();
            newGroup.add(element);
            result.add(newGroup);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public interface GroupFunction<E> {
    public boolean sameGroup(final E element1, final E element2);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, preferably by using guava?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Sure it is possible, and even easier with Guava :) Use [`Multimaps.index(Iterable, Function)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
ImmutableListMultimap<E, E> indexed = Multimaps.index(list, groupFunction);
```

If you give concrete use case it would be easier to show it in action.

Example from docs:

```
List<String> badGuys =
   Arrays.asList("Inky", "Blinky", "Pinky", "Pinky", "Clyde");
Function<String, Integer> stringLengthFunction = ...;
Multimap<Integer, String> index =
   Multimaps.index(badGuys, stringLengthFunction);
System.out.println(index);
```

prints

```
{4=[Inky], 6=[Blinky], 5=[Pinky, Pinky, Clyde]}
```

In your case if GroupFunction is defined as:

```
GroupFunction<String> groupFunction = new GroupFunction<String>() {
  @Override public String sameGroup(final String s1, final String s2) {
    return s1.length().equals(s2.length());
  }
}
```

then it would translate to:

```
Function<String, Integer> stringLengthFunction = new Function<String, Integer>() {
  @Override public Integer apply(final String s) {
    return s.length();
  }
}
```

which is possible `stringLengthFunction` implementation used in Guava's example.

---

Finally, in Java 8, whole snippet could be even simpler, as lambas and method references are concise enough to be inlined:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<E, E> indexed = Multimaps.index(list, String::length);
```

For pure Java 8 (no Guava) example using [`Collector.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) see [Jeffrey Bosboom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25953796/708434), although there are few differences in that approach:

- it doesn't return `ImmutableListMultimap` but rather `Map` with `Collection` values,
- > *There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned* ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)),
- it's a bit more verbose than Guava + method reference.

---

**EDIT**: If you don't care about indexed keys you can fetch grouped values:

```
List<List<E>> grouped = Lists.transform(indexed.keySet().asList(), new Function<E, List<E>>() {
        @Override public List<E> apply(E key) {
            return indexed.get(key);
        }
});

// or the same view, but with Java 8 lambdas:
List<List<E>> grouped = Lists.transform(indexed.keySet().asList(), indexed::get);
```

what gives you `Lists<List<E>>` view which contents can be easily copied to `ArrayList` or  just used as is, as you wanted in first place. Also note that `indexed.get(key)` is `ImmutableList`.

```
// bonus: similar as above, but not a view, instead collecting to list using streams:
List<List<E>> grouped = indexed.keySet().stream()
    .map(indexed::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT 2**: As  Petr Gladkikh mentions [in comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463543/grouping-elements-of-a-list-into-sublists-maybe-by-using-guava/8464106#comment28969950_8464106), if `Collection<List<E>>` is enough, above example could be simpler:

```
Collection<List<E>> grouped = indexed.asMap().values();
```

Comment: This is exactly the situation `Multimap` was designed for.

Comment: In place of last code example `indexed.asMap().values()` would probably suffice to get `Collection<List<E>>`

Comment: How to use String as index for grouping in Guava?

Comment: @Alex78191 What do you mean exactly? Seems like a separate question.

Comment: @Xaerxess ok, I found out . Replaced Integer with String.

Answer (score 12):

[`Collector.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) from the Java 8 streams library provides the same functionality as Guava's `Multimaps.index`.  Here's the example in [Xaerxess's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464106/3614835), rewritten to use Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> badGuys = Arrays.asList("Inky", "Blinky", "Pinky", "Pinky", "Clyde");
Map<Integer, List<String>> index = badGuys.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
System.out.println(index);
```

This will print

```
{4=[Inky], 5=[Pinky, Pinky, Clyde], 6=[Blinky]}
```

If you want to combine the values with the same key in some other way than creating a list, you can use the overload of `groupingBy` that takes another collector.  This example concatenates the strings with a delimiter:

```
Map<Integer, String> index = badGuys.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, Collectors.joining(" and ")));
```

This will print

```
{4=Inky, 5=Pinky and Pinky and Clyde, 6=Blinky}
```

If you have a large list or your grouping function is expensive, you can go parallel using `parallelStream` and a concurrent collector.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> index = badGuys.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(String::length));
```

This may print (the order is no longer deterministic)

```
{4=[Inky], 5=[Pinky, Clyde, Pinky], 6=[Blinky]}
```

Comment: For multilevel grouping you can group by List<string> of property values.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and simplest way would be using: [Lambdaj grouping feature](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures)

The above example can be re-written:

```
List<String> badGuys = Arrays.asList("Inky", "Blinky", "Pinky", "Pinky", "Clyde");
Group group = group(badGuys, by(on(String.class).length)));
System.out.println(group.keySet());
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, Guava and few helper functions you can implement grouping with custom Comparator

```
public static <T> Map<T, List<T>> group(List<T> items, Comparator<T> comparator)
{
    ListMultimap<T, T> blocks = LinkedListMultimap.create();

    if (!ArrayUtils.isNullOrEmpty(items))
    {
        T currentItem = null;

        for (T item : items)
        {
            if (currentItem == null || comparator.compare(currentItem, item) != 0)
            {
                currentItem = item;
            }

            blocks.put(currentItem, ObjectUtils.clone(item));
        }
    }

    return Multimaps.asMap(blocks);
}
```

Example

```
Comparator<SportExercise> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(SportExercise::getEstimatedTime)
                .thenComparingInt(SportExercise::getActiveTime).thenComparingInt(SportExercise::getIntervalCount)
                .thenComparingLong(SportExercise::getExerciseId);

Map<SportExercise, List<SportExercise>> blocks = group(sportWorkout.getTrainingExercises(), comparator);

blocks.forEach((key, values) -> {
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.println(values);
        });
```