# Group a list of objects by an attribute

Tags: java, list, grouping

I need to group a list of objects (`Student`) using an attribute (`Location`) of the particular object. The code is like below:

```
public class Grouping {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studlist.add(new Student("1726", "John", "New York"));
        studlist.add(new Student("4321", "Max", "California"));
        studlist.add(new Student("2234", "Andrew", "Los Angeles"));
        studlist.add(new Student("5223", "Michael", "New York"));
        studlist.add(new Student("7765", "Sam", "California"));
        studlist.add(new Student("3442", "Mark", "New York"));

    }
}

class Student {
    String stud_id;
    String stud_name;
    String stud_location;

    Student(String sid, String sname, String slocation) {
        this.stud_id = sid;
        this.stud_name = sname;
        this.stud_location = slocation;
    }
}
```

Please suggest me a clean way to do it.

Comment: A hashmap with location as the key and the students list as value.

Comment: Would sorting by location solve your problem, or is there something else?

Comment: Try using Comparator and sort by location.

Comment: @Warlord Yes, But going further if I need get information like, Student count by Location better if I could get it grouped

Comment: @Omoro Please can you give me a clue by code, Im not so familiar with Hashmaps

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra check one of the answers below.

Comment: I think the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8464106/673086 also applies to this problem.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This will add the students object to the [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with `locationID` as key.

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Student>> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Student>>();
```

*Iterate* over this code and add students to the `HashMap`:

```
if (!hashMap.containsKey(locationId)) {
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(student);

    hashMap.put(locationId, list);
} else {
    hashMap.get(locationId).add(student);
}
```

If you want all the student with particular location details then you can use this:

```
hashMap.get(locationId);
```

which will get you all the students with the same the location ID.

Comment: You declared a List of Location objects  and in the next line you add a Student object to the previous list which should throw an error.

Comment: hashMap.get() returns null when hashMap.contanisKey() return false. You could save the call to containsKey() method if you call first hashMap.get(), store result in a local var, and check if this local var is null

Answer (score 377):

In Java 8:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studlistGrouped =
    studlist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.stud_location));
```

Comment: That is because in `Student` class `stud_location` is specified as Friendly. Only `Student` class and any class that is defined in the same package of `Student` can access `stud_location`. 
If you put `public String stud_location;` instead of `String stud_location;`, this should work. Or you can define a getter function.

More info in https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 35):

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();

for (Student student : studlist) {
    String key  = student.stud_location;
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
        List<Student> list = map.get(key);
        list.add(student);

    }else{
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(student);
        map.put(key, list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17):

### Java 8 groupingBy Collector

Probably it's late but I like to share an improved idea to this problem. This is basically the same of @Vitalii Fedorenko's answer but more handly to play around.

You can just use the `Collectors.groupingBy()` by passing the grouping logic as function parameter and you will get the splitted list with the key parameter mapping. Note that using `Optional` is used to avoid the unwanted NPE when the provided list is `null`

```
public static <E, K> Map<K, List<E>> groupBy(List<E> list, Function<E, K> keyFunction) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(list)
            .orElseGet(ArrayList::new)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyFunction));
}
```

Now you can *groupBy* anything with this. For the use case here in the question

`Map<String, List<Student>> map = groupBy(studlist, Student::getLocation);`

Maybe you would like to look into this also [Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)

Answer (score 12):

Using **Java 8**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Student {

    private String stud_id;
    private String stud_name;
    private String stud_location;

    public String getStud_id() {
        return stud_id;
    }

    public String getStud_name() {
        return stud_name;
    }

    public String getStud_location() {
        return stud_location;
    }



    Student(String sid, String sname, String slocation) {

        this.stud_id = sid;
        this.stud_name = sname;
        this.stud_location = slocation;

    }
}

class Temp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Stream<Student> studs = 
        Stream.of(new Student("1726", "John", "New York"),
                new Student("4321", "Max", "California"),
                new Student("2234", "Max", "Los Angeles"),
                new Student("7765", "Sam", "California"));
        Map<String, Map<Object, List<Student>>> map= studs.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStud_name,Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStud_location)));
                System.out.println(map);//print by name and then location
    }

}
```

The result will be:

```
{
    Max={
        Los Angeles=[Student@214c265e], 
        California=[Student@448139f0]
    }, 
    John={
        New York=[Student@7cca494b]
    }, 
    Sam={
        California=[Student@7ba4f24f]
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by sticking to the same example as the question. Also the result does not match with the desired output requested in the question.

Comment: nice explanation.

Comment: Don't write Java code as C developer :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> groupedStudents = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
for (Student student: studlist) {
    String key = student.stud_location;
    if (groupedStudents.get(key) == null) {
        groupedStudents.put(key, new ArrayList<Student>());
    }
    groupedStudents.get(key).add(student);
}
```

//print

```
Set<String> groupedStudentsKeySet = groupedCustomer.keySet();
for (String location: groupedStudentsKeySet) {
   List<Student> stdnts = groupedStudents.get(location);
   for (Student student : stdnts) {
        System.out.println("ID : "+student.stud_id+"\t"+"Name : "+student.stud_name+"\t"+"Location : "+student.stud_location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement SQL GROUP BY Feature in Java using Comparator, comparator will compare your column data, and sort it. Basically if you keep sorted data that looks as grouped data, for example if you have same repeated column data then sort mechanism sort them keeping same data one side and then look for other data which is dissimilar data. This indirectly viewed as GROUPING of same data.

```
public class GroupByFeatureInJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductBean p1 = new ProductBean("P1", 20, new Date());
        ProductBean p2 = new ProductBean("P1", 30, new Date());
        ProductBean p3 = new ProductBean("P2", 20, new Date());
        ProductBean p4 = new ProductBean("P1", 20, new Date());
        ProductBean p5 = new ProductBean("P3", 60, new Date());
        ProductBean p6 = new ProductBean("P1", 20, new Date());

        List<ProductBean> list = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p3);
        list.add(p4);
        list.add(p5);
        list.add(p6);

        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ProductBean bean = (ProductBean) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(bean);
        }
        System.out.println("******** AFTER GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID ******");
        Collections.sort(list, new ProductBean().new CompareByProductID());
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ProductBean bean = (ProductBean) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(bean);
        }

        System.out.println("******** AFTER GROUP BY PRICE ******");
        Collections.sort(list, new ProductBean().new CompareByProductPrice());
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            ProductBean bean = (ProductBean) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(bean);
        }
    }
}

class ProductBean {
    String productId;
    int price;
    Date date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductBean [" + productId + " " + price + " " + date + "]";
    }
    ProductBean() {
    }
    ProductBean(String productId, int price, Date date) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
    }
    class CompareByProductID implements Comparator<ProductBean> {
        public int compare(ProductBean p1, ProductBean p2) {
            if (p1.productId.compareTo(p2.productId) > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (p1.productId.compareTo(p2.productId) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            // at this point all a.b,c,d are equal... so return "equal"
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.equals(obj);
        }
    }

    class CompareByProductPrice implements Comparator<ProductBean> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ProductBean p1, ProductBean p2) {
            // this mean the first column is tied in thee two rows
            if (p1.price > p2.price) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (p1.price < p2.price) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.equals(obj);
        }
    }

    class CompareByCreateDate implements Comparator<ProductBean> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ProductBean p1, ProductBean p2) {
            if (p1.date.after(p2.date)) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (p1.date.before(p2.date)) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.equals(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is here for the above ProductBean list is done GROUP BY criteria, here if you see the input data that is given list of ProductBean to Collections.sort(list, object of Comparator for your required column) This will sort based on your comparator implementation and you will be able to see the GROUPED data in below output. Hope this helps...

```
    ******** BEFORE GROUPING INPUT DATA LOOKS THIS WAY ******
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 30 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P2 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P3 60 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ******** AFTER GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID ******
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 30 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P2 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P3 60 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]

    ******** AFTER GROUP BY PRICE ******
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P2 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 20 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P1 30 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
    ProductBean [P3 60 Mon Nov 17 09:31:01 IST 2014]
```

Comment: Hi, please don't post the same answer multiple times, and please don't post raw code without an explanation about how it works and how it solves the problem in the question above.

Comment: Sorry buddy, there was some mistake in pasting the code, since it might have become multiple times. I have edited explanation for what I posted. Hope that looks fine now???

Comment: I'm missing something or this code is sorting instead of grouping by a field? I see products sorted by ID, then by Price

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test9 {

    static class Student {

        String stud_id;
        String stud_name;
        String stud_location;

        public Student(String stud_id, String stud_name, String stud_location) {
            super();
            this.stud_id = stud_id;
            this.stud_name = stud_name;
            this.stud_location = stud_location;
        }

        public String getStud_id() {
            return stud_id;
        }

        public void setStud_id(String stud_id) {
            this.stud_id = stud_id;
        }

        public String getStud_name() {
            return stud_name;
        }

        public void setStud_name(String stud_name) {
            this.stud_name = stud_name;
        }

        public String getStud_location() {
            return stud_location;
        }

        public void setStud_location(String stud_location) {
            this.stud_location = stud_location;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return " [stud_id=" + stud_id + ", stud_name=" + stud_name + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("1726", "John Easton", "Lancaster"));
        list.add(new Student("4321", "Max Carrados", "London"));
        list.add(new Student("2234", "Andrew Lewis", "Lancaster"));
        list.add(new Student("5223", "Michael Benson", "Leeds"));
        list.add(new Student("5225", "Sanath Jayasuriya", "Leeds"));
        list.add(new Student("7765", "Samuael Vatican", "California"));
        list.add(new Student("3442", "Mark Farley", "Ladykirk"));
        list.add(new Student("3443", "Alex Stuart", "Ladykirk"));
        list.add(new Student("4321", "Michael Stuart", "California"));

        Map<String, List<Student>> map1  =

                list
                .stream()

            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getStud_id)
                    .thenComparing(Student::getStud_name)
                    .thenComparing(Student::getStud_location)
                    )

                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(

                ch -> ch.stud_location

        ));

        System.out.println(map1);

/*
  Output :

{Ladykirk=[ [stud_id=3442, stud_name=Mark Farley], 
 [stud_id=3443, stud_name=Alex Stuart]], 

 Leeds=[ [stud_id=5223, stud_name=Michael Benson],  
 [stud_id=5225, stud_name=Sanath Jayasuriya]],


  London=[ [stud_id=4321, stud_name=Max Carrados]],


   Lancaster=[ [stud_id=1726, stud_name=John Easton],  

   [stud_id=2234, stud_name=Andrew Lewis]], 


   California=[ [stud_id=4321, stud_name=Michael Stuart],  
   [stud_id=7765, stud_name=Samuael Vatican]]}
*/


    }// main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Student>>();
List<Student> studlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
studlist.add(new Student("1726", "John", "New York"));
map.put("New York", studlist);
```

the keys will be locations and the values list of students. So later you can get a group of students just by using:

```
studlist = map.get("New York");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `guava`'s `Multimaps`

```
@Canonical
class Persion {
     String name
     Integer age
}
List<Persion> list = [
   new Persion("qianzi", 100),
   new Persion("qianzi", 99),
   new Persion("zhijia", 99)
]
println Multimaps.index(list, { Persion p -> return p.name })
```

it print:

> [qianzi:[com.ctcf.message.Persion(qianzi, 100),com.ctcf.message.Persion(qianzi, 88)],zhijia:[com.ctcf.message.Persion(zhijia, 99)]]

Answer (score 0):

```
Function<Student, List<Object>> compositKey = std ->
                Arrays.asList(std.stud_location());
        studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositKey, Collectors.toList()));
```

If you want to add multiple objects for group by you can simply add the object in `compositKey` method separating by a comma:

```
Function<Student, List<Object>> compositKey = std ->
                Arrays.asList(std.stud_location(),std.stud_name());
        studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositKey, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    KeyValuePair<?, ?> that = (KeyValuePair<?, ?>) o;
    return Objects.equals(key, that.key) && Objects.equals(value, that.value);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort like this:

```
    Collections.sort(studlist, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return o1.getStud_location().compareTo(o2.getStud_location());
        }
    });
```

Assuming you also have the getter for location on your Student class.

Comment: Why Sort ? The problem is to group the  elements !