# Java Generics: Error when using innerclass

Tags: java, generics

Based on the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693998/8760211

Following Compile Error occurs, when I try to sort a list with elements of Type `Student` from within the class `Invoker`.
`Student` is an innerclass of class `University`:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ToIntFunction<University.Student> to ToIntFunction<? super T>
```

Code:

```
public class University implements Serializable {
    private List<Student> values = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static final class Student implements Serializable {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String location;
        private Date date;

        Student(int id, String name, String location, Date date) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.location = location;
            this.date = date;
        }

        // Problem occurs even with getters!!
}


public class Invoker implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<University.Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String, Integer> locationOrder = students.stream().collect(HashMap::new,
                (m, s) -> m.putIfAbsent(s.getName(), m.size()),
                (m1, m2) -> m2.keySet().forEach(l -> m1.putIfAbsent(l, m1.size())));

        students.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((University.Student s) -> locationOrder.get(s.name)).thenComparing(s -> s.id));        
    }
}
```

The following code snippet is marked in IDE as cause of the Compiler error:
`comparingInt((University.Student s) -> locationOrder.get(s.name)`

If I move the innerclass into the class `Invoker` everything works fine!!

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange error to get, but the reason is just that `s.name` is not accessible in the `Invoker`: it's private. Neither is `s.id`. So you should add getter methods to `Student` like

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

and use them instead. Enclosing classes can access the inner classes' private members which is why it works if moved to `Invoker`.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Many thanks for your reply. I have the getters in the class Student. But even with those getters I get the compiler error!! It's really very strange.

Comment: I tested by copying your code, making classes non-public (so they can all go in one file) and adding the getters, and it works: https://ideone.com/cQz7R5. Please double-check that your code is as in the question (different code would explain the error much better).

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your reply. Yes, if all classes are in one file it works! But I have to seperated the classes in different files and so then I get the described error!!

Comment: Then something really weird is going on. How exactly are you compiling and running the code?

Comment: Hi Alexey, I'm using eclipse with JDK 1.8. I will try it today with another IDE and then give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks so much, using getName() everywhere solves this problem: `students.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((University.Student s) -> locationOrder.get(s.>>>>getName()<<<<)).thenComparing(s -> s.id));`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this

```
students.sort(Comparator.<University.Student>comparingInt(s -> locationOrder.get(s.name)).thenComparing(s -> s.id));
```

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for your reply. the compile error is solved but the List is sorted by id, so the grouping disappears!! Very odd behavior.

Comment: Well that depends on locationOrder. Is it a map or something?

Comment: Hi Leo, locationOrder is a Map<String, Integer>.