# Array pairwise matching in java give error also store data between two similar element

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, logic

I have two array. They are represent x-coordinates and y-coordinates. The code is like that if both coordinates are same it print a statement **"Both co ordinates are same"** else they print **They are not same**.

My code is

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    double[]xcoordinate={2.3,1.2,3.3,5.5,2.3,1.3,7.9,1.2,3.3,3.3,5.2};
    double[]ycordinate={5.4,2.2,4.4,6.6,5.4,1.9,5.2,2.2,3.5,4.4,4.2};
    int i=0,k=1;
    while(i<xcoordinate.length){
        //if(xcoordinate[i]&&ycordinate[i]==xcoordinate[k]&&ycordinate[k]){
        if(xcoordinate[i]==xcoordinate[k]&&ycordinate[i]==ycordinate[k]){
            System.out.println("Both co ordinates are same");
            i++;
            if(k<xcoordinate.length) {
                k = i + 1;
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("They are not same");
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

If I analysis the array I can see that 2.3 and 5.4 are pair,1.2 and 2.2 are pair and so on. As you can see 2.3 and 5.4 is repeat at 5th pair. So in this time they print **They are same**.

But the code block not run for that if statement.

Error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

How to eliminate this error and also how to store the **They are not same** types of data?

Like want to store{ {1.2,3.3,5.5}and{2.2,4.4,6.6} }and {{3.3,5.5,2.3,1.3,7.9}and{4.4,6.6,5.4,1.9,5.2}} ..... separately.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(xcoordinate[i]  == ycordinate[i]  && xcoordinate[k] == ycordinate[k])`?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your algorithm (pairwise matching). You have a simple syntactical error. Note that left and right operands of && must evaluate to a boolean expression.

Comment: You should use a for-loop instead of while. You will loop infinitely if not all your coordinates are the same.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I change my code block and new problem arise. Now it is related to my pairwise algorithm problem.

Comment: Have edited my code to match your new requirements! hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to change, you have a syntax error:

```
if((xcoordinate[i]==xcoordinate[k])&&(ycordinate[i]==ycordinate[k]))
```

If expressions don't evaluate as you coded.

EDIT 2: Here is the full workable code:

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    double[]xcoordinate={2.3,1.2,3.3,5.5,2.3,1.3,7.9,1.2,3.3,3.3,5.2};
    double[]ycordinate={5.4,2.2,4.4,6.6,5.4,1.9,5.2,2.2,3.5,4.4,4.2};
    for(int i = 0; i < xcoordinate.length; i++)
    for(int k = i+1; k < xcoordinate.length; k++)
            if(xcoordinate[i]==xcoordinate[k]&&ycordinate[i]==ycordinate[k]){
            System.out.println("Both co ordinates are same: " + i + "," + k);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("They are not same" + i + " " + k);
        }
    }
```

EDIT 3: The same functionality, using while loops, the correct way of doing:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    double[]xcoordinate={2.3,1.2,3.3,5.5,2.3,1.3,7.9,1.2,3.3,3.3,5.2};
    double[]ycordinate={5.4,2.2,4.4,6.6,5.4,1.9,5.2,2.2,3.5,4.4,4.2};
    int i = 0;
    while(i < xcoordinate.length)
    {
        int k = i+1;
        while(k < xcoordinate.length)
        {
        if(xcoordinate[i]==xcoordinate[k]&&ycordinate[i]==ycordinate[k]){
            System.out.println("Both co ordinates are same: " + i + "," + k);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("They are not same" + i + " " + k);
        }
        k++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket.

Comment: @Simion I change my code block and new problem arise.

Comment: @Shubham Chopra, you are very wrong, i just wrote the entire code in Java Fiddle, pay attention at the outputs. I didn't ewven looked into your code. Before assuming something you should be sure about that. Second: you did it differently, i do not save the values at all, i do all checks without keeping old indexes. Very rude from your side.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your contribution but the checking you done is not same as I want. When they find a match between i=0,k=4 position then i increment by 1 and the value of k starting from k=i+1 position. So as per your code block (0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),(0,10) this checking never done. Because i already find a match and increment by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer from Simion who is solving your evaluation problem, will you end up having an enless loop, cause you only increment i (i++) when your numbers are the same.

Comment: that is why i have written a well working code below

Comment: Had the editor open for a while didn't saw that you already answered it.

Comment: @ShubhamChopra I change my code block and new problem arise.

Comment: @Saswati what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to keep track of repeating co-ordinates,
If yes, then this might help!

```
int i=0;
HashMap<Double,Double> hst = new HashMap<Double,Double>();
while(i<xcoordinate.length){

    if(hst.containsKey(xcoordinate[i])){
        if(hst.get(xcoordinate[i]) == ycordinate[i])
        System.out.println("Occured before and now again at pos" +i);
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println("Not occured before");
    hst.put(xcoordinate[i],ycordinate[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: That is ok but how could I get the values of those co-ordinates which came not occur before. I want to create a subdata set from actual data set. Like that I mentioned earlier {1.2,3.3,5.5}and{2.2,4.4,6.6} is my 1st sub dataset,{3.3,5.5,2.3,1.3,7.9}and{4.4,6.6,5.4,1.9,5.2} my 2nd sub dataset .... so on.