# What is simplest and the neatest way to implement the solution for the below problem

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, automation

I have been given the data for different cars(Year, Model) in the form of Car, consider 2 streams of data coming into my system.

**Input Data:**

("2018", "i20") 
("2018", "zen") 
("2016", "alto") 
("2015", "k10") 
("2014", "ertiga")
("2016", "i20")

What i need to achieve is that when user enters a valid key e.g "2018" as a search keyword, he should be displayed all the associated car models in the sorted order for that key.

e.g in this case output for "2018" should be : [i20, zen]

I am aware that in java hashmap can't have duplicate keys and did some research also that this can be implemented using MultiMap but would really appreciate some leads here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "this can be implemented using MultiMap" Yes, it sure can. Use it.

Comment: It can also be implemented by just creating an `ArrayList<Car>` which does allow duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group a list of objects by an attribute : Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678430/group-a-list-of-objects-by-an-attribute-java)

Comment: Without using any librarys, a HashMap is perfect for this problem. I think if you spend some time learning about how the Map interface works you will come up with a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put the values into a `Map<String, List<String>>` and get the list using `get(String key)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be implemented using com.google.common.collect.Multimap.
Try below:

```
Multimap<String, String> cars = ArrayListMultimap.create();
cars.put("2018", "i20");
cars.put("2018", "zen");
cars.put("2016", "alto");
cars.put("2015", "k10");
cars.put("2014", "ertiga");
cars.put("2016", "i10");
System.out.println(cars.get("2018"));
```

If you don't want to use a 3rd party library, you can go with

```
Map<String, List<String>>.
```

Comment: 1) you need to specify which 3rd party library you are using and 2) the simplest solution requires a 3rd party lib? really?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Agreed. Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put values in `Map<String, Set<TreeSet>>`
        Where `TreeSet` keeps your value sorted