# How to group by attribute in a list and get max and min of dates from the distinct attribute that is grouped

Tags: java

I have a list that reads like

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
    new Student("1234", "steve", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10")), 
    new Student("1234", "steve", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-11"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-20")),
    new Student("1234", "George", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10")));
```

The domain model of student holds four values `Students = {String class_num, String name, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate}`

I am trying to group by the attribute `name` and get `min(startDate)` and `max(endDate)` for distinct names found in the list.

The expected result for the above input should be

```
{{"1234", "steve", 2019-09-01, 2019-09-20},
{"1234", "George", 2019-09-01, 2019-09-10}}
```

//took the min of date for steve and max of date for steve

Can this be achieved through the use of stream api in java?

Comment: "I want to" is not an actual question, show us what you have tried and explain your issue.

Comment: Also duplicate of: [*Group a list of objects by an attribute : Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21678430/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem of finding minimum and maximum has to be in two separate operations. Therefore, we need to stream twice in order to find out those results.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                new Student("1234", "steve", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10")),
                new Student("1234", "steve", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-11"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-20")),
                new Student("4321", "George", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-01"),  LocalDate.parse("2019-09-10")));

        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, List<Student>> collect = students.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName));

        // finding the minimum start date
        collect.values().forEach(list -> list.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparing(Student::getStartDate))
                .ifPresent(s -> handleResult(result, s.getId(), s.getName(), s.getStartDate())));
        // finding the maximum end date
        collect.values().forEach(list -> list.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Student::getEndDate))
                .ifPresent(s -> handleResult(result, s.getId(), s.getName(), s.getEndDate())));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void handleResult(Map<String, List<String>> result, String id, String name, LocalDate date) {
        if (result.containsKey(id)){
            List<String> strings = result.get(id);
            strings.add(date.toString());
        }else {
            ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            strings.add(id);
            strings.add(name);
            strings.add(date.toString());

            result.put(id, strings);
        }
    }
```

Output

```
{1234=[1234, steve, 2019-09-01, 2019-09-20], 4321=[4321, George, 2019-09-01, 2019-09-10]}
```