# groupping list of objects based on properties in java

Tags: java, list, collections, pojo

I have POJO `List<TravelRequestDTO>` and I want to group and create filtered `List<TravelRequestDTO>` if `leavingFrom,goingTo,onwarDate,returnDate` are same add passenger to same object

Example :

```
Passanger,     onWard,      return,      leavingFrom,     goingTo

  A,            1-2-20,      3-2-20,        BLR,            PUNE

  B,            1-2-20 ,     3-2-20,        BLR,            PUNE
```

final `List<TravelRequestDTO>` should contain :

```
Passanger,     onWard,      return,      leavingFrom,     goingTo

  A,B          1-2-20      3-2-20        BLR            PUNE
```

```java
public class TravelRequestDTO {

    private List<Pax> passangers; 
    private String leavingFrom;
    private String goingTo;
    private String onwarDate;
    private String onwardTime;
    private String returnDate;
    private String returnTime;
    private SegmentTypeEnum segmentType;
    private TravelModeEnum travelMode;
    private String purposeOfVisit;
     }


    public class Pax{

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String mobile;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do you get Pax object, where does DTO stores information of First passenger

Comment: I guess former `List<TravelRequestDTO>` and later `List<TravelRequestDTO>` names must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you need older java version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60050918/11733759), than you can do like this:

```java
Map<Object, List<TravelRequestDTO>> hashMap = new HashMap<Object, List<TravelRequestDTO>>();
for (TravelRequestDTO value: initList) {
    List<Object> key = Arrays.asList(value.getOnWard(),value.getReturn(),value.getLeavingFrom(),value.getGoingTo());
    if (!hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        List<TravelRequestDTO> list = new ArrayList<TravelRequestDTO>();
        list.add(value);
        hashMap.put(key, list);
    } else {
        hashMap.get(key).add(value);
    }
}
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21678430/11733759) for other solution.

It is only half way to what you want. After that you have to extract final result from this map. Or you can do it in one step:

```java
Map<Object, TravelRequestDTO> hashMap = new HashMap<Object, TravelRequestDTO>();
for (TravelRequestDTO value: initList) {
    List<Object> key = Arrays.asList(value.getOnWard(),value.getReturn(),value.getLeavingFrom(),value.getGoingTo());
    if (!hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        TravelRequestDTO item = value; // pass first value or copy it to new
        hashMap.put(key, item);
    } else {
        hashMap.get(key).getPassangers().addAll(value.getPassangers());
    }
}
List<TravelRequestDTO> result = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values());
```

Comment: @abhinandanabhinandan then you can vote up this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code to get a List of TravelRequestDTO objects based on properties.

```
Function<TravelRequestDTO, List<Object>> compositeKey = travelRecord ->
    Arrays.<Object>asList(travelRecord.getOnWard(),travelRecord.getReturn(),travelRecord.getLeavingFrom(),travelRecord.getGoingTo());

Map<Object, List<TravelRequestDTO>> map =
people.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but we need answer for  java 1.7

Comment: Please any one ?  help me