# How can I write this funtion in kotlin being a java developer but switching to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to learn some kotlin since most of Android development is moving to the kotlin language. I have a sample code that I was trying to solve in kotlin

```
class City(val country: String, val name: String, val population: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val cities = arrayOf<City>(
    City(country = "USA", name = "Boston", population = 2500000000),
    City(country = "China", name = "Beijing", population = 100000000),
    City(country = "USA", name = "Atlanta", population = 6000300)
  )

  printCitiesByCountry(cities);
```

I need to write a function printCitiesByCountry(cities) that returns sample
:

- USA = [Boston = 250000000, Atlanta = 6000300]
- China = [Beijing = 100000000]

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, but Africa is a continent, not a country; and Nigeria and Ghana are countries, not cities.  And, more relevantly: in Kotlin, arrays are generally used only for backward compatibility; lists are much more common, as they're more flexible.

Comment: Ha! oh my goodness I am sorry that is indeed a big mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-grouping.html):

```kotlin
class City(val country: String, val name: String, val population: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val cities = arrayOf<City>(
    City(country = "Africa", name = "Nigeria", population = 25000000),
    City(country = "China", name = "Beijing", population = 100000000),
    City(country = "Africa", name = "Ghana", population = 6000300)
  )
  
  printCitiesByCountry(cities)
}

fun printCitiesByCountry(cities: Array<City>) {
    val citiesByContinent = cities.groupBy(keySelector={ it.country }, valueTransform={ "${it.name} = ${it.population}" })
    println(citiesByContinent)
}
```

Comment: How would that function look like in Java using for instance Map<>

Comment: This is what I have so far  List<City> c = new ArrayList<>();
        c.add(new City("USA",  "Boston",  25000000));
        c.add(new City("China",  "Beijing",  25000000));
        c.add(new City("USA",  "Atlanta",  25000000));

        printCitiesByName(c);

Comment: @AnnaMurray I don't understand exactly what you mean. If you want to do this in Java, you'd need to implement something similar to groupBy in Java. A Map<String, List<City>> would be a good way to go about it. Here is an example of doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678430/group-a-list-of-objects-by-an-attribute-java