# Grouping a JPA Entity by getting the concatenation of a field

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, jpa, hashmap

I retrieve from a JPA Repository query an Entity which refers to these table

| Id | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | New York |
| 2 | Paul | Atlanta |
| 3 | Mark | Los Angeles |
| 4 | Susan | Los Angeles |
| 5 | Josh | New York |
| 6 | Charles | Atlanta |

I'd like to group by my List of Entities by City and obtain this response:

```
{"New York":["John","Josh"],"Atlanta":["Paul", "Charles"],"Los Angeles":["Mark","Susan"]}
```

I tried to follow [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678430/group-a-list-of-objects-by-an-attribute) but I only can obtain a Map<String, List< RegistryEntity >. I didn't want these, I want Map<String, List< String >> so I did in these way.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> findAllUsers() {
    List<RegistryEntity> items = registryRepository.findAll();
    Map<String, List<String>> itemsGrouped = new HashMap<>();
    for (RegistryEntity s: items) {
        if (itemsGrouped.get(s.getCity()) != null) {
            itemsGrouped.get(s.getCity()).add(s.getName());
        }
        else {
            List<String> tempResults = new ArrayList<>();
            tempResults.add(s.getCity());
            itemsGrouped.put(s.getName(), tempResults);
        }
    }
    return itemsGrouped;
}
```

The code works, but I'd like to know if there's something more efficient and more elegant to group by my entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stream then you need also [collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [collectors.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), i tried to code something like down below.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> itemsGrouped = 
    items.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               RegistryEntity::getCity,
               Collectors.mapping(RegistryEntity::getName, Collectors.toList()))
           );
```