# How to group elements in ArrayList<CustomObject>

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist, grouping

Is there a simple and fast way to group elements from an ArrayList in Java?
I'm asking if there is already a way without implementing it by my self? something like

```
Collections.sort(monuments,new objectComparator());
```

**EDIT:**
 I have a list of Objects That have a field called category, this list is shown to the user. I want the objects of category_type==1 to be shown first and so on.

I can't achieve this with comparator, since the way the comparator works is like this:

return int a>0 if the first value is bigger
return int a

Comment: What do you mean by _group_?

Comment: You will have to implement the comparator yourself

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: I think you mean SORT, not GROUP

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8464106/673086

Comment: Your question title "How to group elements in ArrayList<CustomObject>" is misleading. It implies something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678430/group-a-list-of-objects-by-an-attribute-java
What you're looking for is a "sort" or maybe converting a list to set (where there's no two entries with the same value), or maybe both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this can be achieved with a comparator:

```
public int compareTo(Monument o) {
    Integer otherCategory = o.getCategoryType();
    Integer thisCategory = this.getCategoryType();
    return thisCategory.compareTo(otherCategory);
}
```

The Comparator will return 0 if they are the same, -1 if `thisCategory` is less than `otherCategory`, and 1 if `thisCategory` is greater than `otherCategory`

Here's a unit test based on this idea:

```
public class SortTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);

        System.out.println("Unsorted: " + list);

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("Sorted: " + list);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
Sorted: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: yes but this doesn't ensure that it will be grouped. for example:
if the list is 1,2,3,4,1 this will return:
1,2,3,1,4

Comment: I don't believe that is true. Have you run a unit test with that assertion?

Comment: sorry my bad, I implemented something similar and didn't work.In you're SortTest why where did you declare that will use the abobe comparator?

Comment: I didn't. My list contains Integers, and we get Integer comparison for free in java. The comparator I provided you actually uses Integer comparison to give you the result you're after. Have your Monument class implement the Comparator interface just like I showed you. Then all you'll need to do is call Collections.sort(list) to get them sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping using a `Map<X, List<CustomObject>>` where X is the grouping (in your case an Integer representing the category_type)

eg:

```
public Map<Integer, List<CustomObject>> groupByCategoryType(List<CustomObject> list) {
    Map<Integer, List<CustomObject>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<CustomObject>>();
    for (CustomObject o : list) {
        List<CustomObject> group = map.get(o.getCategoryType());
        if (group == null) {
           group = new ArrayList();
           map.put(o.getCategoryType(), group);
        }
        group.add(o);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: this seems nice, but I want this function to return a list not a map

Comment: Well... a list is not grouped. I think it's the wrong collection type for what you're trying to do.