# ArrayList groupby in java android based on same attributes without java 8 stream and lambda

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections, guava

My object looks something like below

```
 class Item{
    String color;
    int price;
    int size;
}
```

Now my arraylist contains objects of type item

I want to create sublist of items having same price.

Want to group items into sublist with same color.

Want to create sublist of items with same size.

**Since I am implementing this in android and want to support all android version I can't use Lambda and Stream**

**I want to use CollectionUtils by apache or Guava by google but don't know how to do it any help?**

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463543/grouping-elements-of-a-list-into-sublists-maybe-by-using-guava)

Comment: it is just for String I am looking for objects based on properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Guava, you can create [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) in which keys are your desired property (ex. price) and values are items for each group by using [`Multimaps#index(Iterable, Function)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-).

Note that without lambdas functions are very cumbersome. See a definition of a function for getting price (could be inlined):

```
private static final Function<Item, Integer> TO_PRICE =
  new Function<Item, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Item item) {
      return item.price;
    }
  };
```

Create your grouped multimap:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, Item> byPrice = Multimaps.index(items, TO_PRICE);
```

Sample data:

```
ImmutableList<Item> items = ImmutableList.of(
    new Item("red", 10, 1),
    new Item("yellow", 10, 1),
    new Item("green", 10, 2),
    new Item("green", 42, 4),
    new Item("black", 4, 4)
);
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(byPrice);
// {10=[Item{color=yellow, price=10, size=1}, Item{color=green, price=10, size=2}], 42=[Item{color=green, price=42, size=4}], 4=[Item{color=black, price=4, size=4}]}
System.out.println(byPrice.values());
// [Item{color=yellow, price=10, size=1}, Item{color=green, price=10, size=2}, Item{color=green, price=42, size=4}, Item{color=black, price=4, size=4}]
System.out.println(byPrice.get(10));
//[Item{color=yellow, price=10, size=1}, Item{color=green, price=10, size=2}]
```

Comment: I have List<Item>  items how can I convert them to ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, Item>

Comment: @apk `ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, Item> byPrice = Multimaps.index(items, TO_PRICE);` as mentioned in answer, where `TO_PRICE` is the `Function` you define (either inline or constant, as written above).

Comment: ohh thanks I thought I will have to create ImmutableList first

Comment: `Multimaps#index` accepts any `Iterable`, so any `List`, `Set` or even `Collection` is OK.

Comment: heyy sorry one more query how can I access ImmutableListMultimap by index

Comment: `multimap.get(10)` will get you a list of all `Items` with price `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Map<String, List<Item>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Item item : items) {
   List<Item> list;
   if (map.containsKey(item.getColor())) {
      list = map.get(item.getColor());
   } else {
      list = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   list.add(item);
   map.put(item.getColor(), list);
}
map.values(); // this will give Collection of values.
```

Comment: Looking for more optimised way